# SHA3 in eos contract

Tags: hash

How can I use sha3(keccak) hash in eos contract? There is a sh3 implementation in [cpp-ethereum](https://github.com/ethereum/cpp-ethereum). Can I copy the sha3 file to my smart  contract?

Answer (score 2):

You can run any code you want as long as you need no access to specific system calls. So yes, you can just copy the sha3 file to your smart contract.