# Does eos smart contract support sha3(keccak)?

Tags: smart-contract, ethereum

In the eosiolib/crypto.h, I only saw the sha1, sha256, sha512, ripemd160, and recover keys method.

If I'd like to add the sha3 method, did I need to write the library in the contract?

That will be huge, does the official has the plan to do this?

Comment: see the following link: https://eosio.stackexchange.com/questions/932/sha3-in-eos-contract